# How should we profit from wine?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Gemara in Megillah 7b says

> מיחייב איניש לבסומי בפוריא עד דלא ידע בין ארור המן לברוך מרדכי
>
> A person is obligated to *besumi* on Purim until he doesn't know the difference between the cursedness of Haman and the blessedness of Mordechai.

Now, the word *besumi* is an unusual word, but luckily Rashi is there to tell us what it means:

> להשתכר ביין
>
> To make money with wine

So we have to make money with wine on Purim.

This was easy enough for Rashi, since he had a vineyard and was a wine merchant.  But how are you and I, the common Jew, supposed to profit from wine on Purim?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53605/759 Sell someone the Brooklyn Bridge

Comment: Buy low, sell high...same way you make a profit on anything else.

Answer (score 2):

On Purim when people come to your house to collect, you can sell them wine by the sip, and thus you will be able to become wealthy from wine.