# Leniency to aggrieve a minor (one's child)?

Tags: halacha, minor-katan-child, family-members, kerovim-close-relatives, injury

Causing certain types of harm to one's fellow (for example, stealing or [battering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/is-there-a-halacha-that-prohibits-punching-or-slapping-someone)) is prohibited. But do these laws apply if the victim is a minor? To what extent? What if the minor is one's own child--may one spank him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. #### A mitsva

   See  Mishna Maccot chapter 2, 2:

   > אַבָּא שָׁאוּל אוֹמֵר, מַה חֲטָבַת עֵצִים רְשׁוּת, יָצָא הָאָב הַמַּכֶּה אֶת בְּנוֹ {יא}, וְהָרַב הָרוֹדֶה אֶת תַּלְמִידוֹ, וּשְׁלִיחַ בֵּית דִּין {יב}: ‏
   > Bartenura:
   > מַה חֲטָבַת עֵצִים רְשׁוּת. דְּאִי בָעֵי עָיֵיל לַחְטֹב וְאִי בָעֵי לֹא עָיֵיל: יָצָא הָאָב הָרוֹדֶה אֶת בְּנוֹ. דְּמִצְוָה קָא עֲבִיד:‏
   > Yqar Tosfot Yom Tov:
   > ‏ {יא} אֶת בְּנוֹ. לְהַטּוֹתוֹ לְדֶרֶךְ אַחֶרֶת. רַשִׁ"י:
   >  {יב} וּשְׁלִיחַ בֵּית דִּין. הַמַּלְקֶה אַרְבָּעִים לַחַיָּב מַלְקוֹת. וּלְשׁוֹן הָרַאֲבַ"ד, שְׁלִיחַ בֵּית דִּין שֶׁהוּא מַלְקֶה יוֹתֵר מִמַּה שֶּׁאֲמָדוּהוּ. וְהָרַמְבַּ"ם כָּתַב שֶׁהִכָּה אֶת הַנִּמְנָע לָבֹא לַדִּין וֶהֱמִיתוֹ בִשְׁגָגָה:‏
   > The Galut punishment when someone kills unintentionnally a man. But only if the unintentional killer was involved in an optional activity. So if he was a father which was beating his son, to move it to a favorable direction (Ykar Tosfot Yom Tov), no; because he fulfiles a duty (Bartenura).
2. #### An error

   . In Masechet Evel Rabati they report cases of child which commit suicide from fear of retribution. The above is the general rule but Gemara Baba Batra 21a:

   > התקינו שיהו מושיבין בכל פלך ופלך ומכניסין אותן כבן ט"ז כבן י"ז, ומי שהיה רבו כועס עליו - מבעיט בו ויצא, עד שבא יהושע בן גמלא ותיקן, שיהו מושיבין מלמדי תינוקות בכל מדינה ומדינה ובכל עיר ועיר, ומכניסין אותן כבן שש כבן שבע.‏
   >
   >
   > They therefore ordained that teachers should be appointed In each prefecture, and that boys should enter school at the age of sixteen or seventeen.
   >
   > [They did so] and if the teacher punished them they used to rebel and leave the school.
   >
   >
   > וא''ל רב לרב שמואל בר שילת כי מחית לינוקא לא תימחי אלא בערקתא דמסנא דקארי קארי דלא קארי ליהוי צוותא לחבריה.‏
   > Rab also said to Rabbi Samuel Bar Shilath: When you punish a pupil, only hit him with a shoe latchet {slight tap that will not cause damage}. The attentive one will read [of himself]; and if one is inattentive, put him next to a diligent one.
3. #### To act wisely

   So we see that sometime, the child should be chastised. But if the child will revolt, the operation has failed; if they damage also, because the scope is not to damage. See the excellent answer above which quotes Rav Wolbe Zatsal.

Masechet Evel Rabbati chapter  2:

> הלכה ד
>   מעשה בבנו של גורנוס(?) בלוד שברח מבית הספר והראה לו אביו באזנו ונתירא מאביו והלך ואבד עצמו בבגד ובאו ושאלו את רבי טרפון ואמר אין מונעין הימנו כל דבר.
>
> הלכה ה
>   מעשה בתינוק אחד מבני ברק ששבר צלוחית בשבת והראה לו אביו באזנו ונתירא מאביו והלך ואבד עצמו בבור ושאלו את רבי עקיבא ואמר אין מונעין הימנו כל דבר.
>
> הלכה ו
>   מכאן אמרו חכמים אל יראה אדם לתינוק באזנו אלא מלקיהו מיד או ישתוק ולא יאמר לו כלום.‏

The  threat of punishment can lead a child to suicide,  so  Chachamim prohibited this practice.

Comment: `they report cases of child which commit suicide from fear of retribution.` your source says nothing about the children or anyone else committing suicide.

Answer (score 1):

In the blog [Daat Torah](http://daattorah.blogspot.com/2013/04/hitting-kids-is-wrong-because-it-causes.html), the author (I do not know who it is) quotes [Rabbi Horowitz](http://www.rabbihorowitz.com/PYes/ArticleDetails.cfm?Book_ID=1120&). Rabbi Horowitz's website claims (I think correctly) that he is recognized throughout the Jewish community as an authority on raising children in these troubled times.

Rabbi Horowitz quotes Rav Pam

> due to the enhanced sense of personal freedom and individual rights
>   nowadays (and this was a generation ago), hitting children is unwise
>   and counterproductive

and Rav Wolbe

> that parents who consider hitting their children, should be
>   aware that their children will ‘hit them back’ for each and every
>   potch when they grow older, by rebelling against their authority and
>   teachings

Rabbi Horowitz adds his own reasons why hitting is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks and completely agree. However, I am wondering what the halachos are, technically.