# Punishment for assault

Tags: sin, reward-punishment

I'm familiar with jewish laws governing murder, but I can't recall ever having heard of jewish laws which govern assault.

What are some of the rules concerning classifying and punishing people who commit assault?

Comment: Read Babba Kamma chapter 8; Rambam chovel umazik ch 1-8 http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088906/jewish/Chovel-uMazzik.htm

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/is-there-a-halacha-that-prohibits-punching-or-slapping-someone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Business Halacha Institute [writes](http://businesshalacha.com/en/folder-money-matters/damages):

> A person who inflicts physical injury is liable for a five-part
>   payment: nezek (disability), tzaar (pain), ripuy (medical
>   expenditures), sheves (lost wages), and boshes (embarrassment) —
>   whichever are relevant (C.M. 420:3).
>
> Nezek relates to the inherent, permanent disability of the injury,
>   such as loss of limb or ability to see or hear. Tzaar is payment for
>   the pain and suffering associated with the assault or injury, even if
>   there is no disability. Ripuy covers medical expenditures associated
>   with healing the injury. Sheves covers the temporary loss of wages
>   while the victim is convalescing. [Permanent loss of work due to
>   disability is included in nezek.] Boshes covers the embarrassment
>   inflicted on the victim through injuring or hitting him. This payment
>   is required only when the perpetrator intended to embarrass or injure
>   (C.M. 421:1, 11).

Comment: The question was about "classifying and punishing" assaulters (and indeed mentions murderers as an analogue, and they're punished and pay no damages). This is about restitution (damages). I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @msh210, generally speaking _halacha_ provides only restitution not punishment for assault. (And קם ליה בדרבה מיניה usually means restitution and punishment are mutually exclusive.) I don’t recall the source, but for assault whose restitution is less than nominal value (שווה פרוטה) the punishment is lashes, for violation of לא יסיף (Devarim 25:3).

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, if you find the sources, I recommend you post an answer.